# Batch-converting multimedia-files on Command-Line using find and ffmpeg (Linux)

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, find, multimedia

For converting more Audio-Files (Let's say, FLAC to MP3) in the same folder on Command-Line, I formerly used

```
find ./ -name "*.flac" -exec ffmpeg -i "{}" -b:a 320k "{}".mp3 \;
```

but the problem is that the resulting MP3-Files are named like Artist - Title.flac.mp3. 
This doesn't even surprise me, but what do I have to type if I want to avoid the ".flac.mp3"-Filenames? 
The converted Files should be named like Artist - Title.mp3, not this .flac.mp3 
I didn't yet find a way to solve this problem ... 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hope that helps. 
I did not test it but if there's any typo, I hope you get the idea.

```
find ./ -name "*.flac" -exec ffmpeg -i "{}" -b:a 320k "{}".mp3 \; -exec rename 's/\.flac//' {} \;
```